# Erlang List Tuple Match

Tags: list, erlang, tuples

Im learning Erlang
suppose I have two lists

```
[{a,a,a,b,c},{d,d,a,a,b},{a,b,c,d,e}]
[{{a,a,a,a,a},10},{{a,a,a,a},6},{{a,a,a},4}]
```

after Patten Match, expected result {a,a,a,b,c} because it can match {{a,a,a},4}

I tried **lists:keysearch** and  **lists:member**, but cannot get expected result

any suggestion?

thanks

Comment: How does `{a,a,a,b,c}` match `{{a,a,a},4}`? Could you explain how does  are those two the same?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to match {a,a,a|_} {a,a,a,b,c}. is this possible?

Comment: Still not sure. Why `{a,a,a,b,c}` wouldn't match `{{a,a,a,a,a},10}`? Tuples usually represent some kind of whole connected data; if you are trying to use only part of them, maybe try to represent it as lists? And for me it's rally hard to come up with generic algorithm if I don't really understand what are you trying to represent? Maybe try to describe logic behind your matching, from where you get your input, and where you will use your output.  That might help me a little.

Comment: No, it is not directly possible. Tuples are one block of data so you match **whole tuples** with each other. So to match `{a,b,c}` you would need a pattern like `{A,B,C}`.

Comment: Now that I've gone and written an answer, I'm considering editing the question to improve and generalize it so that others may find it. Matching seems to be a stumbling block for early learners and I'd hate for the subject to be difficult to investigate. Any objections or recommendations (anyone)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matching is not consumptive. Your mental model of how matching works is confusing set operations (like set subtraction and intersection) with comparison and assignment. Your concept of set operations might also benefit from some review.

Erlang's matching is *only* for assignment and assertion (a sort of comparison). If we match an unbound variable (never used before) against any value, the variable will be bound (assigned) that value:

```
Foo = {a,b,c}.
```

Now `Foo` and `{a,b,c}` can be used interchangeably. This is pure symbolic assignment like in math class, not a "variable" in the sense of other languages where variables are "storage boxes for values".

If we use the `=` operator against any value and this now bound symbol `Foo`, we are doing a check comparison (an assertion) not an assignment. `Foo` can't mean anything other than `{a,b,c}` in the current context, so trying to assign it any different value causes an exception, but simply stating that `{a,b,c}` is `{a.b.c}` is correct and still yields `{a,b,c}` (and since `Foo` is now a symbol for `{a,b,c}` it can appear on either side and still the statement is correct).

Doing

```
{a,b,c} = {a,b,c}.
```

or

```
{a,b,c} = Foo.
```

or

```
Foo = {a,b,c}.
```

returns `{a,b,c}`, and does not raise an exception because all we did here was *assert* that `{a,b,c}` is indeed `{a,b,c}`.

If I want just the first value assigned, I can match another way:

```
{Bar,_,_} = {a,b,c}.
```

Now `Bar` represents `a`, and the `_` values are ignored (completely skipped). The original `{a,b,c}` has *not been changed*. This is also true if we do:

```
{_,Baz,_} = Foo.
```

Now `Baz` represents `b`, and `Foo` still represents `{a,b,c}`. And that's about it. When it comes to lists, like `[{a,b,c}, {1,2,3}]` we can still do matching, but because of the nature of lists we will check a piece at a time (try this in the interpreter):

```
Spam = [{a,b,c}, {1,2,3}].
[Boo | _] = [{a,b,c}, {1,2,3}].
```

Now `Boo` represents `{a,b,c}`, and `Spam` *still* represents its original list.

That's about all there is to matching. The magical thing about Erlang's pattern matching is not how it works, its how many places provide natural opportunities for pattern matching, and how this winds up naturally solving a huge number of problems that require procedural checks or direct assignment operations in other languages (cond, function parameters, `=`, message reception, etc.).

Set and list operations are not the same thing as pattern matching in Erlang. I suggest going through some basic learning material first, like some of the many good beginner tutorials and [Learn You Some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/).

Comment: thank you for answer. feel free to edit the question.